# Double tap zoom in text area - iOS, Titanium

Tags: ios, textview, titanium, zooming, double-click

In my iOS app there have a View with -

```
View
   Scroll View
      Text Area
```

On 'Pinch' gesture, the scroll view helps in zooming the view in-and-out. 
I have a requirement that, on 'double tap', the view has to return to normal - zoom Scale - 1.0.
But, 'double tap' on the text area has 'copy,Paste' etc options shown.
Can anyone help me with the below logic - whether its possible or not -

```
On double tap
   If(zoomed in/out view)
      Bring view to normal
   else
      Show the 'copy,paste' options
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the long press what usually brings up copy/paste? How do you have the double-tap doing that?

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom in / out, set the TextArea's touchEnabled method to false, so that it will not respond to the double tap functionality you have set. Add the doubletap listener to the ScrollView, and have it set the zoomScale attribute of itself to 1.0. When that happens Set the TextArea's touchEnabled to true, essentially allowing text to be copy / pasted again.